# Rest Replay Attacks / Security

Tags: web-services, security, rest, jersey, restful-url

let me describe a simple scenario:

There is a rest resource represented by this URI: /api/messages/{userid}. After the user is logged in, a request is dispatched passing to this URI "userid" (logged user). This way, as soon as the user logs in, he gets his own messages based on his ID.

If user is not logged yet, the URI is not visible (there is a authentication filter).

The problem is: if a already logged user discover this uri, he can submit a request passing another ID what will lead to a security problem because he will be able to get messages from another user (simply passing any random ID).

Can you propose any security model to prevent this security flaw ? (what I believe its more likely a cross-cutting concern).

Thanks, in advance!

Comment: then don't auth based on just the url. use a cookie to convey the auth data. without that cookie, the url would be useless.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just off the top of my head, have the endpoint either (a) only return those messages visible by the logged-in user, or (b) only return messages if the logged-in user is the same as the userId in the URI. Which one depends on your business rules.

Comment: What you suggest is to get user id at server side on every request passing this ID to the service (business) layer?

Adopting some principles of Web Services Rest, the server is completely stateless and I would like to implement this more as a cross-cutting concept. My question is how to implement it this way.

Comment: @MikeH I don't see how my reply is invalidated by this concern. Your API must have some way of tracking who is making the request: auth header, API key, etc. That will tell you who the logged-in user is. No state required. If you do (b), you could have a filter check incoming URIs for the userId and compare it to the username. I guess that would be cross-cutting.

Comment: @MikeH Ah, I see, you *don't* have any way of tracking who is logged in. This is a mistake. I will *strongly* suggest you don't write your own web security architecture. Use something that already exists: Basic Auth, OAuth 2, etc.

Comment: How do you recommend implementing that with OAuth 2 to solve the mentioned scenario?

Comment: lookazis -> http://porterhead.blogspot.co.uk/2014/05/securing-rest-services-with-spring.html

Answer (score 0):

In the endpoint you can check for the user and then see if that user id matches the pathparam 
finding the userid from the user name is as easy as selecting the id using the user name from a database

```
import javax.ws.rs.core.Context;
import javax.ws.rs.core.SecurityContext; 
import ... blablabla;

@GET
@Path("messages/{userid}")
public Response getMessages( @PathParam("userid") int userId, @Context SecurityContext context ) {

    String username = context.getUserPrincipal().getName();
    int id = getIdFromName(username); // define this yourself
    if(userId==id) {
        // output the message list
        List<Message> msgs = getDemMessagesGURL(); // define this yourself
        return Response.ok(new GenericEntity<List<T>>(msgs) {}).build();
    } else {
        // output Forbidden(403)
        return Response.status(403).build();
    }

}
```

and with oauth you can use a servlet filter to set the user principal based on the oauth signiture